# Displaying a c# code preview as a UI element (ISuggestedAction.GetPreviewAsync - Visual Studio Extension)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-lightbulbs

I want to display a code preview in the `GetPreviewAsync` method on my clas `ISuggestedAction`.

```cs
public class BaseAction : ISuggestedAction
{
    ...

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets an object visually representing a preview of the suggested action.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   cancellationToken:
    //     A cancellation token that allows to cancel preview creation.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A task whose result is an object visually representing a preview of the suggested
    //     action, or null if no preview can be provided.
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     The only currently supported type of preview object is System.Windows.UIElement.
    //     By default preview panel gets highlighted when focused by setting background
    //     color to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.LightBulbPresenterStyle.PreviewFocusBackgroundBrush.
    //     When providing a preview object make sure it doesn't set different background
    //     for the whole preview content, otherwise it's recommended that preview object
    //     indicates focused state using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.LightBulbPresenterStyle.PreviewFocusBackgroundBrush
    //     color.
    public async Task<object> GetPreviewAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // How do I return c# code to preview?
    }
    
    ...
}
```

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.language.intellisense.isuggestedaction.getpreviewasync?view=visualstudiosdk-2022), it requires a `UIElement` object to be used for the preview.

Where kind of `UIElement` would be used for previewing code? I want the same kind of UI as used for the existing code snippet generation provided by Visual Studio. (See below)

[image]

I am also curious about how to get the `Preview Changes` button just like is present in the default light bulb actions.